# Unable to run multiple instances of libVLC(MobileVLCKit) in IOS via flutter framework

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, libvlc

I am trying to make an application in flutter(for android and IOS) that can run multiple instances of VLC. I choose vlc player because it can run both 'rtsp' and '.ts' file(required for my project).
Presently, I am using two instances of VlcPlayer in my flutter application. And it works fine in android but it gives a bad memory access while running on simulator. More details are given below. I want to know that is it possible to run 2 or more instances of vlc player in IOS and if yes, How?

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel unknown, 2.5.3, on macOS 12.0.1 21A559 darwin-arm, locale
    en-IN)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.6)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.62.3)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
```

Some of my flutter code

```
class _VlcPLayerInstance extends State<VlcPLayerInstance> {
  late VlcPlayerController _controller;
  late VlcPlayerController _controller1;
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _controller = VlcPlayerController.asset("assets/images/video.mp4");
    _controller1 = VlcPlayerController.asset("assets/images/video1.mp4");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          VlcPlayer(controller: _controller, aspectRatio: 1.78),
          VlcPlayer(controller: _controller1, aspectRatio: 1.78),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The output of the code in android is:
[Android Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiNzo.jpg)

But the app crashes and gives the following exception for the same code in IOS simulator.

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000030
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000030
VM Region Info: 0x30 is not in any region.  Bytes before following region: 4366811088
      REGION TYPE                    START - END         [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      UNUSED SPACE AT START
--->  
      __TEXT                      104484000-1044b8000    [  208K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  ...er.app/Runner
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: SIGNAL 11 Segmentation fault: 11
Terminating Process: exc handler [15755]

Triggered by Thread:  2

Thread 2 Crashed::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.opengl.cvmDoWork
0   libCoreVMClient.dylib                  0x1ac31a82c cvmsServerElementBuild + 432
1   libCoreVMClient.dylib                  0x1ac31ab20 cvmsServerElementBuild + 1188
2   libCoreVMClient.dylib                  0x1ac316aec cvms_element_build_from_source + 132
3   libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib             0x1ac30d680 cvm_deferred_build_modular(void*) + 396
4   libdispatch.dylib                      0x18010a6c8 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
5   libdispatch.dylib                      0x180111800 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 652
6   libdispatch.dylib                      0x180112384 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 400
7   libdispatch.dylib                      0x18011cb44 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 744
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1c7fdad58 _pthread_wqthread + 284
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1c7fd9b10 start_wqthread + 8
```

Can anyone help me resolve the problem?
For reference VLCPlayerPlugin in flutter uses MobileVLCKit(~> 3.3.17).

Comment: I think VLCKit enforces a singleton pattern

Comment: You should use a single instance of VLCKit with multiple instances of VLCMediaPlayer. This is well supported to play multiple media at once.